# Prove that a proper subset $E$ of $\Bbb R^n$ is connected $\iff$ it contains exactly two relatively clopen sets.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, self-learning

Prove that a proper subset $E$ of $\Bbb R^n$ is connected $\iff$ it contains exactly two relatively clopen sets.

---

I researched the meaning of "clopen set". And I reached the result that so as to for a set $A$ be clopen, the set $A$ need to be both closed and open.

---

I cannot do this proof. Please help me to do this. Thank you

Comment: Could you add your definition of connectedness as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll use the term "open" in the following as "open for the subspace topology inherited by $E$".

$\Rightarrow$: Assume that $E$ is connected. This means that the union of two disjoint non-empty open subsets of $E$ is not $E$ itself. So let's have $X$ a clopen set of $E$. $E\setminus X$ is open, then, and $E = X \cup (E\setminus X)$. What can you conclude with the remark I made above?

$\Leftarrow$: you know that $\emptyset$ and $E$ are clopen sets, so the hypothesis implies that there are no other clopen set. What can you get from this?

Comment: For $\Rightarrow$, let $U=X$ and $V=E$\$X$ be relatively open subsets of $E$ then $E=U\cup V$ also, $U\cap V\not= \emptyset$ thus, E is not connected.

Comment: For ⇒, let U=X and $V=E\$$X$ be relatively open subsets of E then $E=U\cup V$ also,$U\cap V\not= \emptyset$ thus, E is not connected. –

Comment: For $\Rightarrow$, let $U=X$ and V= E\X be relatively open two subsets of E.

Comment: Then, $E=U\cup V$ and $U \cap V \not= \emptyset$

Comment: Thus, E is not connected.

Comment: Sorry for unreadable first two comments. The last three comments explain hopefully.

Comment: You can delete/edit your previous comments if you need to. And you can't conclude that $E$ is not connected, because $U$ or $V$ may be empty, and this is exactly the point. Because $E = U\cup V$ and $E$ is connected, you get that either $U = E$ or $U = \emptyset$, which gives exactly two clopen sets, as needed!

Comment: That's what my said is trivial. Okay I understand the first part:)

Comment: Conversly, If $\emptyset $ and $E$ be exactly two relatively clopen subsets of $E$,then $E=\emptyset \cup E$.  Since $\emptyset $ and $E$ are relatively clopen, they are also relatively open. That's they are open sets. So, $E$ is union of open sets. So E is not connected. Contradiction. Thus, E must contain more than two clopen sets.